# Is it bad practice to reference one of two possible tables from a third?

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to store two similar but unrelated types in two tables (`A` and `B`).

I also have a table `C`.

Items from `A` or `B` can be related to `C`.

When querying I want to be able to get all relationships to `C` irrespetive of whether they come from `A` or `B`.

Is it bad practice to use a single table `D` that I can store these relationships in? Something like

```
 __________________________________________
|         |                |               |
| id_of_c | id_of_relation | relation_type |
|_________|________________|_______________|
|    1    |        1       |       A       |
|    1    |        2       |       A       |
|    2    |        1       |       A       |
|    3    |        1       |       B       |
|_________|________________|_______________|
```

I know that doing this prevents me from using foreign keys but most of my queries will be of the types:

> I know the ID of C, get me all associations.

OR

> I know the ID and type of A (or B), get me all C's that it's linked to.

It might also be worth noting that I'll programatically only allow `C`'s to be associated with `A`'s OR `B`'s not both.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I don't believe it's bad practice since some popular frameworks (e.g Rails, Hibernate) model, what they refer to as, Polymorphic Association with the same table structure. However, it is important to note, and as you've mentioned, it is not possible to use foreign key constraints with this structure.

While there are alternatives in SQL which would allow a similar result without violating normal forms they each tend to have their own caveats.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best practice is to create two tables for the relationship between A and C, and B and C.

Table D_A:

```
ID_A   ID_C
1      2
2      1
```

Table D_B:

```
ID_B   ID_C
1      3
2      1
```

- you can always extend one of the tables D_C or D_B without extending the other
- you can use foreign keys to make relationship between tables
- no need for a third column
- joins are easier (you don't have to check for the third column to know for sure which table you will join)